# SOAP WS - Payload returns 403 in Java, but success in SOAPUI

Tags: java, soap, cxf, jax-ws, ws

Using:

- Springboot 2.5.2
- Java 11
- CXF 3.4.3

The problem: I call the webservice and I get this error (403):

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '403: Forbidden' when communicating with <the url goes here>
```

I am writing out the payload for the call in console. So I get that same payload, I paste it in SOAPUI and it works like a charm. No further authorization is requested. All credentials travel in that same payloads that fails from Java code but works well from SOAPUI.

For detailed configuration, this is the relevant part of my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I generate the sources using this plugin (jaxws):

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <args>
                <arg>-B-XautoNameResolution</arg>
                <arg>-extension</arg>
            </args>
            <wsdlUrls>
                <wsdlUrl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myWsdl.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
            </wsdlUrls>
            <keep>true</keep>
            <packageName>my.package</packageName>
            <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I also have tried with this plugin (cxf):

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myWsdl.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

What else can be checked?

Comment: *"I get that same payload, I paste it in SOAPUI and it works like a charm"* Are you making the calls from the same machine? Are you sending the request to the same URL address and the parameters of the HTTP call are the same?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes to all the questions.

Comment: Hmmm... Something must be different though, otherwise you would get the same response in both cases.

Comment: Yep... thank you. I was thinking in something related to SSL (WSDL is under https)